# ValueError <ipython-input-65-8da781e9d890>

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I faced a problem when I run deep learning with kerase lib. at the second line below code.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.15, random_state = 42)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 10, batch_size=32)
```

the full code in deep learning is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, SpatialDropout1D

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

import re
embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 196
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1500, embed_dim,input_length = 18))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1500, split=' ')

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(output['text'].values)

X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(dataset1['text'])

X = pad_sequences(X)
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

Le = LabelEncoder()

y = Le.fit_transform(dataset1['sentiment'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.15, random_state = 42)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 10, batch_size=32)
```

the text of error:

```
Epoch 1/10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-89-8da781e9d890> in <module>
      1 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.15, random_state = 42)
      2 
----> 3 model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 10, batch_size=32)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1098                 _r=1):    1099            callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)    1101               if data_handler.should_sync:    1102                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    723     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected( 
# pylint: disable=protected-access
    726             *args, **kwds))
    727 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in
_get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)    2967       args, kwargs = None, None    2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    2970     return graph_function    2971 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in
_maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    3359     3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function    3363 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in
_create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)    3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names    3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(    3197             self._name,    3198             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417
_call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:755 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:203
__call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:152
__call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1608 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4979 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\amal_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:173 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

        raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((32, 2) vs (32, 1))
```

Comment: please post the full error as text

Comment: @WaveShaper OK,done

Answer (score 0):

Add `Flatten` layer before your first layer with `input_shape=[32, 18]` and import `Flatten` from `keras.layers`. Like This before embed layer:

`model.add(Flatten(input_shape=[32, 18]))`

Comment: thanks but the error still exists
also, I tried to change the inputSize=18 , just the warning is fixed but the error not fix

Answer (score 0):

```
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
```

Your dim is not same.just as @Anurag Dhadse advise, you can also add a flatten in this place.

When you build you model,you can use `model.summary()` to review your input shape or output shape

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).